# Same mesh displayed differently on different machines

Tags: mesh, armature, rigging, makehuman

I have file of a mesh and it appears normally in Blender, on my Windows machine, as shown below
[image: correct output]

But when I open the same file using Blender, on my Ubuntu machine it appears like below

[image: wrong output]

So, could anyone explain why is it displaying weirdly on Ubuntu (lower one), meanwhile, on Windows (upper one) it's ok?

Comment: Is it the same Blender version? Are you in shaded mode (Z)?

Comment: @Pisurquatre Yes, same verion but one windows and the other ubuntu. I don't know if I'm in shaded mode or not, how to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the blender version used. Upgrading the version to the latest one solved it.

Comment: please post information on the version used so others can be aware of the issue.

Comment: I have had a similar problem. It's most likely due to whatever plugins you are using for rigging (rigify?)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows you're in weight-paint mode and in Ubunto you're in wireframe view (in object mode).  If you want to change the Ubuntu version, hover over the 3D view and hit Ctrl+Tab to switch modes.  Alternatively, use the menus at the bottom of the 3D view to switch between modes (see screenshot).

[image: wireframe vs weight paint]

Comment: I've done this but whenever I choose the object mode and solid it keeps the same, but strangely I find the armature the one changing not the mesh. Not sure why this is happening may be an issue with the blender version on my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: When you're in Object Mode and Solid view the body remains a wireframe?  Try moving the body mesh to a different layer so that you can work with it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender when you save a file, the user interface for that file gets saved as well. You can choose to use the file's user interface when you open it on a different system.

File->Open (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>) [image]

When the next window opens to select the file press <kbd>T</kbd> to enable the tool shelf
and look for the **Load UI** option on the bottom left side of the screen.
[image]

Comment: tried this but still loaded like that can't switch to solid mode